# Mobile Connect - Conditional Media Response

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I've a use case where I have to show different media in media response SMS. If the user responds with 1 they will see a specific movie file if they respond with 2 they will see a different movie file. Has anyone implemented something similar? Thanks for your help!

Comment: your response could use ampscript to determine what message to send

Comment: I don't know how to play a movie file within that AMPScript block, please note I'm not looking to embed the URL.